# removing item from databinded combobox

Tags: c#, combobox, datasource

In my code I am just trying to implement autocomplete combobox having ability to search substring for this I do following coding on keypress event but as my data in combobox is binded by database so I get error: `Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property set`.

Please correct my code below:

```
cboAuthor.DroppedDown = true;

object[] originalList = (object[])cboAuthor.Tag;
if (originalList == null)
{
 // backup original list
 originalList = new object[cboAuthor.Items.Count];
 cboAuthor.Items.CopyTo(originalList, 0);
 cboAuthor.Tag = originalList;
}

// prepare list of matching items
string s = cboAuthor.Text.ToLower();
IEnumerable<object newList = originalList;
if (s.Length  0)
{
 newList = originalList.Where(item = item.ToString().ToLower().Contains(s));
}

// clear list (loop through it, otherwise the cursor would move to the beginning of the textbox...)
while (cboAuthor.Items.Count  0)
{
 cboAuthor.Items.RemoveAt(0);

}

// re-set list
cboAuthor.Items.AddRange(newList.ToArray());
```

Comment: find out how to use ListCollectionView with Filter . https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I am working in windows form

Comment: @ArunaVerma : send me your code in mail : gaurav@brillbrains.com

Comment: @ArunaVerma the soulotion is still in the same direction what collectionview does is provides you with a filter ability in order to create a view ( a view like in a DataBase ( which does not actually remove items but only presentes a subset of them . 

this can be achived in winforms using BindingSoruce

Comment: The error gives you th hint: Remove it from the datasource!